# Django in template using if tag compare one variable with a number always give false

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I first use **widthratio** tag to calculate a ratio percentage number and assgign it to a variable named Ratio
Then when I try to compare it with an integer in **if** and **elif** tag, the **if** and **elif** tag seems all goes false, and I alway go to the final **else** tag and get the wrong result.
Below is my source code:

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <p><span class="icon-group"></span> Player registratered:  {{event.Players_registratered}}/{{event.Max_players}}</p>
        {% widthratio event.Players_registratered event.Max_players 100 as Ratio %}
        {{Ratio}}
        <div class="progress progress-striped active text-center">
          {% if Ratio < 30 %}
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar"
                        aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{Ratio}}%">
            </div>
          {% elif Ratio < 70 %}
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"
                        aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{Ratio}}%">
            </div>
          {% elif Ratio < 90 %}
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar"
                        aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{Ratio}}%">
            </div>
          {% else %}
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar"
                        aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{Ratio}}%">
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
```

and the output snip:[Wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqHuz.jpg)

I hope someone could answer it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The screenshot looks fine, what exactly is not correct about it? If you went to the last `else` condition each time, all bars would be 100%.

Comment: is Ratio a Number? The if elif would always be wrong if Ratio is a String

Comment: The two variables I used in the Widthratio tag are integer in the models.py
And I am not sure if it is cast to String or not in the tag when I assign the result to Ratio.
By the way, when I use {{Ratio | add :"5"}} it will give me right calculate answer.

Comment: Why you don't use `with` in the beginning of your `withratio` tag ? like this:
`{% with widthratio event.Players_registratered event.Max_players 100 as Ratio %}`

Comment: Thanks gunner. I use `with` and `endwith` tag before 'if' and 'endif', but the problem still exist.
The variable Ratio seems exist all the way with out using 'with' tag.